# Group by two columns, to get uniq result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I want to group the results from one table by two column: `created_at` `p_id`, I need to group it by `p_id` because I need unique values, and I tried using `distinct` in order to do that but in my case didn't work how I wanted.

```
Report.group("date(created_at)").group(:p_id).select("date(created_at) as created_at, count(*) as count, p_id")

r = _
r.count will generate this:
{[Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 11]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 8]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 13]=>1, [Mon, 18   Nov 2013, 12]=>3, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 10]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 7]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 3]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 2]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 9]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 14]=>1, [Mon, 18 Nov 2013, 6]=>1}
```

But I need the result in a different format, what should I add in order to get something like this: `{Mon, 18 Nov 2013=>11}` where `11` is the total number of records generated by the above sql statement.

Thank you.

Comment: i don't understand your question. please provide a better example.

Comment: You are grouping by `p_id` and then you want to ungroup by the same value? Why don't you simply remove the `group(:p_id)` call?

Comment: I edited my question, and to be much clear, what I want to do, is to get for each day the total number of unique `p_id`s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count the number of times a date appear on your result, you can do this via simple ruby code:

```
result = result.inject ({}) do |hash, el| 
  hash[el[0][0]] ||= 0
  hash[el[0][0]] += 1
  hash
}
```

Assuming result is something like this:

```
{[date1, a] => b, [date1, c] => d, [date2, e] => f}
```

you'll get

```
{date1 => 2, date2 => 1}
```

If you'd like to get the `count(*)` value related to a date, change the sum call to this:

```
hash[el[0][0]] += el[1]
```

In this case you'll get:

```
{date1 => b+d, date2 => f}
```

Comment: My results are like your assumed but is still not working. This is the result that I get running the above SQL querie, `[#<Report id: nil, p_id: 32, created_at: "2013-11-19">, #<Report id: nil, p_id: 43, created_at: "2013-11-19">, #<Report id: nil, p_id: 10, created_at: "2013-11-19">...` How can I group them again by date and count them? I think this will be the easy solution.

Comment: Can you please clarify what object you obtain from the `Report.group...` line? What you write here differs from what you expressed in the question.

Comment: What I wrote the is what I get when running the query, what I wrote in the question is what I get if a perform a `count` on that query.

Comment: Well, then set `result = Report.group ... .count` and try my code. It should work.

Comment: Omg, I did that 100 times, and it didn't work, now it worked, thank you.